# Circuit Impedance

Tags: impedance, theory

What is the impedance of the following network? My textbook says $$Z = R_i + R + jwL + 1/jwC$$
But I can't seem to make that work.

[image: elnetwork]

Comment: Throw the textbook away - that equation would be correct if all components were in series. What's your analysis so far?

Comment: Z = R_i + (R + jwL) || 1/jwC obviously. But im lost from there. I get a very long term, which is impossible to divide into a real and imaginary part. Since i have to obtain a nyquist plot, i assumed my result was wrong.

Comment: Do you understand complex conjugates?

Comment: hint: 1/(a+jb) * (a-jb)/(a-jb) = a/(a^2+b^2)-jb/(a^2+b^2)

Comment: so my result is Z = R_i + (-L)/(w^2 * L^2 * C + C * R^2) - j * (w * R)/(w^3 * L^2 * C + w * C * R^2). Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
Z &= R_i + \left(\left(R+j\omega L\right)\parallel\frac{1}{j\omega C}\right)\\
\\
&=R_i + \left(\frac{\frac{R}{j\omega C}+\frac{L}{C}}{R+j\omega L+\frac{1}{j\omega C}}\right)\\
\\
&=R_i + \left(\frac{R+j\omega L}{j\omega RC-\omega^2 LC+1}\right)\\
\\
&=\left(\frac{j\omega R_iRC-\omega^2 LCR_i+R_i+R+j\omega L}{j\omega RC-\omega^2 LC+1}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\left(R_i+R-\omega^2 LCR_i\right)+j\omega \left(R_iRC+\omega L\right)}{\left(1-\omega^2 LC\right)+j\omega RC}\\
\\
\end{align}$$

---

Following AndyAka's suggestion:
$$\begin{align}
Z&=\left(\sqrt{\frac{{\left(R_i+R-\omega^2 LCR_i\right)^2+\omega^2 \left(R_iRC+\omega L\right)^2}}{{\left(1-\omega^2 LC\right)^2+\omega^2 R^2C^2}}}\right) \angle \left(\arctan{\left(\frac{R_iRC+\omega L}{R_i+R-\omega^2 LCR_i}\right)}-\arctan{\left(\frac{\omega^2 R^2C^2}{1-\omega^2 LC}\right)}\right)\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Seems to me like you stopped half way!

Comment: Hmm...? Why does it seem like half-way? I was planning on simplifying it to something like \$ **Z**=z\angle \theta\$ but thought it would be too complicated.

Comment: Normally, getting rid of j in the denominator is the "finished" product. It's no biggy.